# Weirdness with one to one relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, belongs-to, has-one

I have a Rails app which is (relatively) simple. I have three models, an Assessment, a User and a Team. A Team has many Users and each User can have an Assessment. Here are truncated versions of the models and their related schemas:

```
class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end


create_table "assessments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "aasm_state"
  t.integer "user_id"
end
```

---

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :assessment
  belongs_to :team, optional: true
end


create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email"
  t.string "name"
  t.string "organisation_type"
  t.string "position"
  t.string "location"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "team_id"
  t.string "locale", default: "en", null: false
end
```

---

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :assessments, through: :users    
end

create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

When I try to get all users in a team who don't have an assessment `(team.users.where(assessment: nil)`), I get the following error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.user_id does not exist
   LINE 1: ...".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."team_id" = $1 AND "users"."u...
                                                                ^
   : SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."team_id" = $1 AND "users"."user_id" IS NULL
```

And the resulting SQL, as the error suggests, is a little screwy:

```
  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."team_id" = $1 AND "users"."user_id" IS NULL
```

And when I try to get a user from an assessment when an assessment does exist, it returns nil.

I suspect I'm doing something REALLY stupid here, but can anyone help?

Comment: If you want the users of a team having no assessment, you could try `team.users.includes(:assessment).where(assessments: { id: nil })`

Comment: You can modify your schema to get it working. Add 'assesment_id' column in user table and remove 'user_id' from assessment table. Then your above code should work fine.

Comment: Nope. Still nothing. I now can't apply a user to an assessment. I get `can't write unknown attribute `user_id``

Comment: you also need to exchange the belongs_to and has_one association between models. Now, assesment has one user and a user belongs to assesment. I know it may not sound good, but it should work as per your need.

Comment: Hmmm. Still nothing, now `assessment.user = User.new` gives me `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.assessment_id does not exist`

Comment: @Pezholio Have you migrated your db to add column 'assessment_id' in User table as I told you in my first comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you need to use a left outer join here. In Rails 5, this could be written as:

```
users = team.users.left_outer_join(:assessment)
                  .where(assessments: { id: nil })
                  .uniq
```

Source: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html

Answer (score 1):

Starting from what you explained in your question, changes that I made to make above query work is:

1. Remove column 'user_id' from Assessment Table.
2. Add column 'assessment_id' in User Table.
3. Remove `has_one :assessment` from User Model and add `belongs_to :assessment` in the User Model.
4. Remove `belongs_to :user` from Assessment Model and add `has_one :user` in Assessment Model.

Only thing to notice is that, `a.user = u` will commit the changes not `u.assessment = a`. (a is assessment, u is user).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response. I decided to go for the response above, as switching round the relations opened up another huge can of worms I didn't want to deal with! I've upvoted though, as it's still a valid response :)